# automatically run piano keys

Tags: android, button, record

I am making a piano for android. I would like to add a record system to my Project.
I want to record like this,

I made two buttons one for (record /stop) and one for (run /stop) record file. I would like to start record file when I click record button and run the record file when I click run button.
When I click the Record button will start recording. In record time, I click on the piano keys, and each key I press  I want them to be registered and When I stop recording, save the file in sdcard. When I clicked the Run button,  Run a file manager then when I click the record file in the file manager run the file and Piano keys (they previously clicked) automatically click when file run.
I don’t have any information about that and I don’t know what codes are for record, run the record file and automatically click the piano’s buttons like that.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat of a design question. What you probably want to do is to create a data structure for your piano, as well as probably a data structure for individual actions associated with user interaction with the piano. So, when the user sends input to the app, an object is created representing that action (e.g. "user pressed a key"). This way, you can then serialize the objects, in order, and that will represent your "record" functionality.

Once your objects are serialized, it should be trivial to write them out to a file. See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html